# Proper way to update UI from EContentAdapter

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I have an econtent adapter that is essentially causing the refresh of numerous tables. While it is theoretically possible to filter all notifications down to the exact notifications that should cause a refresh on the tables, it would be extraordinarily difficult and time-consuming as we have a massive model, and many different events and changes that could possibly trigger a refresh. Also, what often happens is a single "user-event" (like clicking state->new in our application), triggers 4 objects being created behind the scenes, all of which look very similar from the notification standpoint and therefore makes it difficult to filter out. I'm wondering if there is a good way to do some sort of "delayed job" so that the 4 notifications only cause a single refresh. For example, something similar to:

```
public void notifyChanged(final Notification notification)
     super.notifyChanged(notification);
     @Override
     public void run() {
         if(matchesFilters(notification)) { 
           //some sort of check to see if we recently had another event that would have triggered a refresh?
           if(!schedulingJob) {
              scheduleDelayedJob();
           }
         }  
     }
 }
```

Unfortunately I have little experience in jobs and things like that, so it would be very helpful if someone could give assistance in what the proper way of doing this is.

as another example, if someone just hits control-N 20 times in our application very rapidly, it will rapidly create 20 new states, and we would just want to update the UI at the end of those 20 notifications, not refresh 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, Eclipse provides you with all you need for this.  First, GUIs should be updated on the Display thread.  Second, there is a method for asynchronous execution, as follows:

```
final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
workbench.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Do your thing, e.g. refresh()
  }
});
```

What you do in the Runner depends on the GUI framework.  If you're using JFace, you can do a refresh(), which I believe is smart about queuing up work.

Comment: Not exactly what I mean, although that is still helpful.  Essentially, your solution above would still cause "my thing", e.g. refresh() to occur 20 times if 20 notifications were to come down the pipes in 1 second.  Essentially I am looking for something that delays "refreshing" for a little while so that you don't end up with a log-jam of refreshing if the user does things very quickly.